# Laravel & Redis - job killed after 10 minutes despite timeout set to 1800s

Tags: laravel, redis

I am using multiple redis queues on my laravel application for managing reoccurring tasks.

Everything is working fine except the jobs that are pushed to a queue that are usually running longer than 10 minutes - round about 9-15 minutes.

On Laravel forge I created a new worker on a redis queue with timeout 1800 but still jobs running longer than 10 minutes got terminated. Jobs under 10 minutes are working as intended.

Is there any configuration I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the retry_after value to 1800 in config/queue.php.

You can create multiple redis queues which use the same connection, and dispatch your job on a specified queue.

queue.php:

```
'redis' => [
    'connection' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_CONNECTION'),
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'queue'  => 'default',
    'retry_after => 60
],
'redis_low' => [
    'connection' => env('QUEUE_REDIS_CONNECTION'),
    'driver' => 'redis',
    'queue'  => 'email',
    'retry_after => 1800
]
```

In your job:

```
Job::dispatch()->onQueue('email');
```

Comment: Is it possible to do that for every queue separately? I don't want the other queues to retry failed jobs after such a long time.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated answer.